# How to find the value of a key in a dictionary that is part of a list with multiple dictionaries. (pulled from an api

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm using an api to pull in this List. 
I need the user to be able to enter in the 'name' of airline. Then, once the name is captured, match the 'name' to the 'icao' code within the same Dictionary.

My code

```
import requests 
api-url= ("https://api.url")
class airlinenames(Component):
    def start(self):
        name = "Ali Airlines"
        url = API_URL
        data = requests.get(url).json()

        icao = data['airlines'][0]['icao']

        text = ( "this is your airline: {name} and this is the icao code: {icao}"
        ).format(
           name=name,
           icao=icao
        )
        message = self.create_message(text=text)
        return self.respond(message=message, action="next"
```

My issue is, instead of pulling in the matching 'icao' from the same dictionary, it pulls in the very next one at the top.

So for example if user enters in "Ali Airline"
It should read " This is your airline: Ali Airline,  your ICAO code is: ALI

Example list:

```
{
"airlines": [
  { 
   "fs": "BS",
   "iata": "BS",
   "icao": "ALI",
   "name": "Ali Airlines",
   "active": true
  },
  {
   "fs": "BS*",
   "iata": "BS",
   "icao": "BAL",
   "name": "Bali Airline",
   "active": true
  },
  {
   "fs": "BSK",
   "iata": "LL",
   "icao": "GAL",
   "name": "Gali airline",
   "active": true
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, in the code you provided you are always getting the the very first airline (data['airlines'][0]).

Instead, you should probably convert your data into a dictionary keyed by airline name first, e.g.:

```
airlines = { a['name'] : a for a in data['airlines']}
```

Now, with that dictionary and the name variable, you can find the corresponding code:

```
icao = airlines[name]['icao'] # This will give you the code give a name.
```

Comment: Yes Hinson! Perfect!